# Angular file upload throws error 415 'unsupported media type' & 'Missing or Invalid Url'

Tags: file-upload, angular-file-upload, http-status-code-415

I am trying to upload a file with angular and spring boot, and it is throwing error 415 "unsupported media type" & "Missing or Invalid Url".

The api works fine when tested with Postman. But in Postman also, we need to pass content type as application/json for one of the two form-data values i.e. pathUrl.
[Postman Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gw4c.png)

There are 2 ways in which I am converting data before sending request to upload :

1. I am trying to convert data before sending request like below :
   `let formData = new FormData(); formData.append('file', files[0]); formData.append('pathUrl', JSON.stringify(pathUrl));`

I am getting this error for above try:
"status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type","

2. I am trying to convert data again as below so that I am able to pass content type as application/json for pathUrl :
   `let formData = new FormData(); let request = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ pathUrl: pathUrl }) ], { type: application/json, }); formData.append('file', files[0]); formData.append('pathUrl', request);`

I am getting thie error for above try :
"Missing or Invalid Url".

What am I doing wrong? How do I need to pass data so that it works like how it is working in Postman as shown above.

Could anyone please help. Thanks in advance.